# Foreach items if item is from one of the type/category

Tags: php

I'm looking to foreach items from php array where type is the "key".
Show all items where one of the type is type-2.

Thank you

```
 <?php $gallery = [];
       $gallery [1] = [
       "Name" => "Three Full Length Mirrors",
       "Description" => "Three mirrors with silver aluminum profile. ",
       "image" => "full-mirror.jpg",
       "type" => [
                "type-1",
                "type-2",
                "type-3"
            ]
        ];
    ?>
```

Comment: Can please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to pre-filter the array, but it's just as easy to put the test in your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($gallery as $g) {
    if (!in_array('type-2', $g['type'])) continue;
    // rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 


$result = array_filter($gallaries, function($gallery){
    // If below is true element stays, the false cases get removed from array
    return in_array('type-2',$gallery['type'])
});
```